# How does GDB know where an executable has been relocated?

Tags: gdb, relocation

I know modern OSs such as Linux don't always execute an application at the same address it was originally linked. When a debugger starts looking around though, it needs to know the relationship between the original link address and the final executing address. How does GDB calculate the offset?

Clarifications: I'm not talking about virtual memory. That is, I have (what I believe to be) a reasonable understanding of how Virtual memory works and am operating entirely with in that address space. I have symbols that are at one location when I dump the symbol table from the ELF, but at another location when I get their address out of memory.

In this particular case, I have a string which in the linked executable is at address 0x0E984141. In a dump of memory from that process, it is at address 0x0E3F2781. Everything in the .rodata section at least has been shifted by 0x5919C0. It appears to be something like Address Space Layout Randomization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know modern OSs such as Linux don't always execute an application at the same address it was originally linked.

This is only possible for position-independent executables (linked with `-pie` flag).

> When a debugger starts looking around though, it needs to know the relationship between the original link address and the final executing address.

Correct.

> How does GDB calculate the offset?

The same way GDB calculates the offset for shared libraries (a `PIE` executable is really a special case of a shared library). There is a defined interface between `ld.so` and GDB, consisting of `_dl_debug_state()` function (on which GDB sets an internal breakpoint, and which `ld.so` calls whenever it maps a new `ELF` image into the process), and `struct r_debug`. The latter points to a linked list of `struct link_map`s, and `l_addr` member of that struct is the offset between linked-at and loaded-at address.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand what you are getting at, I think what you are actually referring to is Virtual Memory addressing This is not handled by GDB, it is handled by the operating system.

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/witchel/372/lectures/15.VirtualMemory.pdf

Comment: I don't think this question is about virtual memory, but the fact that ELF segments can get loaded at different locations (in virtual memory) than the addresses (in virtual memory) the ELF file specifies for those segments. For an executable, this happens for instance when you have ASLR.

Answer (score -2):

On Linux,  every process has its own [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) in [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

The [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable contains a header describing the segments in memory (and their corresponding sections in the executable).

Comment: With ASLR, the segments can be loaded at different addresses than what the ELF file specifies.